# only the single row which is selected has to be edited in codeigniter

Tags: tinymce

the code is as follows using the below code when am clicking edit button every is getting the tinymce editor to edit instead to get in the particular row i have selected. what was wrong am doing here?
and also after editing i need to update the data into database.

```
    <?php foreach($result as $r): ?>
<tr  class="editable"  >
<td><?php echo $r->content_s_no; ?>  </td>
<td><?php echo $r->content; ?>  </td>
<td><input type="button" value="edit" class="edit"/>

</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: where are you calling the tinymice script.. please post that

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".edit").click(function()
{
tinymce.init({
    selector: "tr.editable",
    inline: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".save").click(function()
{
});
});
</script>

Comment: bipen i have sent code regarding to tinymce.